# NameError: name 'height' is not defined on line 10

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, nameerror

I'm currently creating a game for a school project on Python. This is what I have so far and Python's telling me NameError: name 'height' is not defined on line 10. What does this mean? I've done lots of research, but I still can't figure it out. Can someone help me?

```
import turtle
enter code here`import random

def main():
  wn=turtle.Screen();
  Gameturtle=turtle.Turtle()

  Setupuser(Gameturtle,wn)
  Setupcontrols(Gameturtle,wn)
  Randomanglegenerator(turtle,len,height)

  li = []
  InsertEnemyturtleintolist(li)
  while (True):
    Hitchecker(Gameturtle, li)

def Setupuser(myTurtle,window):
  window.bgcolor("white")
  #width=x height=y
  window.setup (width=400, height=400, startx=100, starty=100)
  myTurtle.speed(2)
  myTurtle.shape('turtle')
  myTurtle.penup()
  myTurtle.delay(0)
  myTurtle.left(90)

  myTurtle.mainloop()

  window.exitonclick ()

def Hitchecker(myTurtle, enemyTurtles):
  for eturtle in enemyTurtles:
    distance=myTurtle.distance(eturtle)
    if distance <= 1:
       print("You lost a life >:^D")

def InsertEnemyturtleintolist(list):
  Enemy=turtle.Turtle()
  Enemy.shape=("triangle")
  Enemy.speed(5)
  Enemy.penup()
  Enemy.left(90)
  Enemy.showturtle()
  list.append(Enemy)

def Setupcontrols(turtle, window):
  window.onkey(lambda: turtle.goto(turtle.xcor(), turtle.ycor()+15), 'w')
  window.onkey(lambda: turtle.goto(turtle.xcor()-15, turtle.ycor()), 'a')
  window.onkey(lambda: turtle.goto(turtle.xcor()+15, turtle.ycor()), 'd')
  window.onkey(lambda: turtle.goto(turtle.xcor(), turtle.ycor()-15), 's')

  window.listen()


def Randomanglegenerator(turtle,len,height):

 XYcord = random.randrange(1,5)
 print(XYcord)
 if XYcord==2 or 4:
    Enemy.setheading(90)

main()
```

Comment: you are calling Randomanglegenerator method by passing turtle,len,height parrameters.
you haven't initialized these parameters anywhere in your main() method.
parameter turtle is not complaining, because it is an imported lib, so found by main.
len is a keyword in python, so recognized by main, height is the only one remaining that has no existing definition, so your code is thowing error for height.

Ideally, all the parameters that you are passing to your function should be defined/initiated in your main.

Comment: Every variable you reference in your function must be defined (assigned to, or passed in as a parameter) before it is accessed.  For example, what value do you expect `height` to have when you pass it to `Randomanglegenerator`?  What value *could* it have?  Python has never seen it before.  You need to *tell* it, by assigning something to it.

Comment: Please provide the entire error message. As an aside, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your program.  First, invalid or questionable Python syntax:

```
if XYcord==2 or 4:
wn=turtle.Screen();
```

Should be something like:

```
if XYcord == 2 or XYcord == 4:
wn = turtle.Screen()
```

These are equivalent methods and you should use one or the other, not both.  And `mainloop()` is a method of the screen or a function in the package 'turtle', not a method of a turtle instance:

```
myTurtle.mainloop()
window.exitonclick()
```

Instead do:

```
window.mainloop()
```

or:

```
window.exitonclick()
```

Redefining Python built-ins like `list` is a *bad* idea:

```
def InsertEnemyturtleintolist(list):
    ...
    list.append(Enemy)
```

instead do:

```
def InsertEnemyturtleintolist(myEnemiesList):
    ...
    myEnemiesList.append(Enemy)
```

Finally, an *infinite loop* like this has no place in an event-driven world like turtle:

```
while (True):
```

we need to replace it with a *timer event*.  Below is my rewrite of your code to address the above issues and get it to basically function:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randrange

def main():
    screen = Screen()
    turtle = Turtle()

    SetupUser(turtle, screen)
    SetupControls(turtle, screen)

    RandomAngleGenerator(turtle)

    enemies = []
    for _ in range(5):
        InsertEnemyTurtleIntoList(enemies, turtle)

    HitChecker(turtle, screen, enemies)

    screen.mainloop()

def SetupUser(myTurtle, myScreen):
    myScreen.bgcolor('white')
    myScreen.setup(width=400, height=400, startx=100, starty=100)

    myTurtle.speed('slow')
    myTurtle.shape('turtle')
    myTurtle.penup()

def SetupControls(myTurtle, myScreen):
    myScreen.onkey(lambda: myTurtle.sety(myTurtle.ycor() + 15), 'w')
    myScreen.onkey(lambda: myTurtle.setx(myTurtle.xcor() - 15), 'a')
    myScreen.onkey(lambda: myTurtle.setx(myTurtle.xcor() + 15), 'd')
    myScreen.onkey(lambda: myTurtle.sety(myTurtle.ycor() - 15), 's')

    myScreen.listen()

def HitChecker(myTurtle, myScreen, enemyTurtles):
    dead = False

    for myEnemy in enemyTurtles:
        if myTurtle.distance(myEnemy) <= 10:
            print("You lost a life >:^D")
            dead = True
            break

    if dead:
        myScreen.onkey(None, 'w')
        myScreen.onkey(None, 'a')
        myScreen.onkey(None, 'd')
        myScreen.onkey(None, 's')
    else:
        myScreen.ontimer(lambda: HitChecker(myTurtle, myScreen, enemyTurtles), 100)

def InsertEnemyTurtleIntoList(array, myTurtle):
    enemy = Turtle()
    enemy.hideturtle()
    enemy.shape('triangle')
    enemy.speed('normal')
    enemy.penup()
    enemy.left(90)
    enemy.showturtle()

    while enemy.distance(myTurtle) < 30:
        enemy.setposition(randrange(-190, 190), randrange(-190, 190))

    array.append(enemy)

def RandomAngleGenerator(myTurtle):

    turns = randrange(1, 3)

    for _ in range(turns):
        myTurtle.left(90)

main()
```

I'm sure it doesn't do *everything* you want it to do yet, but this should give you a workable starting point to finish your program.